# Why does Rescale performance vary significantly based on the real number values in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, data, performance-tuning

I have a list of the form:

```
testList = Table[{Flatten[RandomReal[{-200, 200}, {1, 2}], 1], RandomReal[{-200, 200}, {69, 2}]}, {i, 1, 100}];
```

And I would like to perform the following rescaling operation very quickly:

```
Rescale[testList, {-160 Sqrt[5], 160 Sqrt[2]}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

And indeed we see that this takes about $\approx 1$ millisecond.

However, if we manually specify testList:

```
riggedTestList = {{72.0003, 254.632}, {{0., 0.}, {164.523, -1.48019}, {-36.4013, -1.6529}, {-30.6006, -9.68836}, {79.1769, -9.38496}, {127.414, -13.3351}, {26.2267, -14.9839}, {101.471, -17.2131}, {112.759, -20.2044}, {140.786, -20.3125}, {152.117, -23.4485}, {171.028, -28.6424}, {128.855, -34.8548}, {67.2216, -48.2581}, {-58.5145, -53.227}, {147.275, -52.8399}, {-2.11577, -54.7374}, {160.367, -57.3066}, {-43.8697, -59.9146}, {50.3993, -63.4993}, {105.478, -64.6626}, {-38.5779, -73.1765}, {167.692, -74.2231}, {38.1779, -75.0274}, {182.719, -75.3023}, {101.273, -76.3709}, {91.2674, -78.7477}, {140.126, -83.058}, {167.292, -83.068}, {-30.6985, -90.7144}, {73.0603, -91.5605}, {15.3827, -93.4644}, {168.049, -97.4066}, {101.349, -97.9227}, {148.875, -105.038}, {-27.7536, -106.1}, {119.991, -110.415}, {170.865, -110.703}, {-1.03466, -111.89}, {96.2519, -121.383}, {179.463, -127.087}, {-62.9256, -127.913}, {172.077, -131.731}, {-41.8538, -137.851}, {171.768, -143.748}, {28.4562, -146.02}, {71.0586, -145.51}, {149.767, -146.569}, {37.6894, -150.356}, {-26.1955, -159.44}, {-41.9501, -163.069}, {135.019, -164.213}, {-62.5847, -172.048}, {7.02217, -174.589}, {133.175, -175.744}, {0.392205, -184.99}, {56.418, -189.734}, {83.9584, -196.068}, {-9.36728, -198.523}, {141.564, -197.764}, {43.6112, -200.002}, {133.577, -201.431}, {16.5308, -203.89}, {79.8118, -207.938}, {178.305, -210.113}, {-45.2895, -216.227}, {-4.60035, -234.998}, {3.16025, -240.952}, {78.6896, -248.948}}};

riggedTestList = Table[riggedTestList, {i, 1, 100}];
```

And then attempt the same rescale on this array with the same dimensions as testList:

```
Rescale[riggedTestList, {-160 Sqrt[5], 160 Sqrt[2]}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The `Rescale` operation takes $\approx 33$ milliseconds, a difference of over an order of magnitude.  How could this be the case?  Both `` Developer`PackedArrayQ[testList] `` and `` Developer`PackedArrayQ[riggedTestList] `` return `False`, so I don't think it's a list packing issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, it is all about packing.  By using `RandomReal` you an generating packed *sub-arrays* even if the complete array is not packed (and can't be, due to irregular shape):

```
Map[PackedArrayQ, testList, {2}] // Short
```

> ```
> {{True,True},{True,True},{True,True},{True,True},{True,True},<<91>>,{True,True},
>  {True,True},{True,True},{True,True}}
> ```

Let's look at some timings more closely:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

Needs["Developer`"]

Rescale[testList, {-160 Sqrt[5], 160 Sqrt[2]}] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.0005744
> ```

```
Rescale[riggedTestList, {-160 Sqrt[5], 160 Sqrt[2]}] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.0256
> ```

Fully unpacking `testList` results in the same timing as `riggedTestList`:

```
unpacked = FromPackedArray @ testList;
Rescale[unpacked, {-160 Sqrt[5], 160 Sqrt[2]}] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.0256
> ```

Packing `riggedTestList` in the same degree as `testList` also matches the faster timing:

```
repacked = Map[ToPackedArray, riggedTestList, {2}];
Rescale[repacked, {-160 Sqrt[5], 160 Sqrt[2]}] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.0005744
> ```

---

Addressing a comment below, in version 7 under Windows the results are equivalent as expected:

```
Rescale[testList, {-160 Sqrt[5], 160 Sqrt[2]}] == 
  Rescale[unpacked, {-160 Sqrt[5], 160 Sqrt[2]}]

Rescale[riggedTestList, {-160 Sqrt[5], 160 Sqrt[2]}] == 
  Rescale[repacked, {-160 Sqrt[5], 160 Sqrt[2]}]
```

> True
>
> True

Comment: Ahh, I should have looked at the sublists.

Comment: @RM1618 These things are fairly tricky.  I didn't understand this stuff until someone else showed me.

Comment: Well thanks for passing along the knowledge.

Comment: @RM1618 For that you're always welcome. :-)

Comment: Is it possible to have repacked actually look like Rescale[riggedTestList, {-160 Sqrt[5], 160 Sqrt[2]}] after rescaling?  For me on version 9, I'm not seeing the Rescale operation performed?

Comment: Thanks, it would be great to achieve the kind of speedup we're observing with packed sublists.

Comment: @RM1618 Could you run the final lines I added to my answer, after running the rest, and tell me if you also get `True` and `True` or not?

Comment: Yes, True and True.  What was it?  We just needed to add the line: Needs["Developer`"]?  Odd since PackedArrayQ didn't require this?

Comment: @RM1618 `PackedArrayQ`, `ToPackedArray` etc. are all in the ``Developer` `` context; by using ``Needs["Developer`"]`` we can leave off the context because it is added to the `$ContextPath`.

Comment: @RM1618 I just read my own comment above: "I am surprised that..." I was starting to write a completely different comment and accidentally left that in.  I am *not* surprised by the contexts. :^) lol